# jhipster Keycloak Invalid parameter: redirect_uri ssl

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I just generate a monolithic app with OAuth(1st time) running here 
https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8020/

I set up the Keycloak here
https://keycloak.nms.blaucomm.co.uk/auth/realms/emfit/account

When I try to login it gives this error in the Keycloak logs:

```
 type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=emfit, clientId=account, userId=null, ipAddress=xxxxxxx, error=invalid_redirect_uri, redirect_uri=https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8020/login/oauth2/code/oidc
```

Where do I configure the uri?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Is working now]

With this configuration is working now